# algorithm to find duplicates

Tags: algorithm, file, duplicates

Are there any famous algorithms to efficiently find duplicates?

For e.g. Suppose if I have thousands of photos and the photos are named with unique names. There could be chances that duplicate could exist in different sub-folders. Is using std::map or any other hash-maps is a good idea?

Comment: So problem can be rephrased as: Given a Tree, find duplicate nodes with same data content?

Comment: You can use the `HashMap` to very efficiently find if the some value already stored.

Comment: Are you looking for 2 files with the same name or 2 files with different name and identical contents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your dealing with files, one idea is to first verify the file's lenght, and then generate a hash just for the files that have the same size.

Then just compare the file's hashes. If they're the same, you've got a duplicate file.

There's a tradeoff between safety and accuracy: there might happen, who knows, to have different files with the same hash. So you can improve your solution: generate a simple, fast hash to find the dups. When they're different, you have different files. When they're equal, generate a second hash. If the second hash is different, you just had a false positive. If they're equal again, probably you have a real duplicate.

In other words:

```
generate file sizes
for each file, verify if there's some with the same size.
if you have any, then generate a fast hash for them.
compare the hashes.
If different, ignore.
If equal: generate a second hash.
Compare.
If different, ignore.
If equal, you have two identical files.
```

Doing a hash for every file will take too much time and will be useless if most of your files are different.

Comment: Once you have a hash collision, it might be just as easy to compare the files directly instead of computing a second hash for each. Although a second hash might be a good idea if there's an n-way collision for some n > 2.)

Comment: which comparison method is faster? Binary comparison or CRC based comparison? I feel Binary comparison is faster and also possible to execute in parallel.

Comment: @Ted Hoop : yes, I thought that you could have multiple collision. But your point is a good one: If you have just a 2-file-collision, one could compare them byte-by-byte.

Comment: @sarat: and if you have to compare 5 files? You can calculate 5 hashes and compare them, or you'd have to compare A against B, C, D and E, them B against C, D and E, them... I think it would take longer.@Ted Hoop has a good point when you have just 2 files, iwth more files it would take longer to binary compare them.

Comment: Conversely, doing a hash at all might take too much time if most of your files have duplicates, e.g. when importing a few new files from a digital camera which retains lots of already imported files on it.

Comment: I've seen this algorithm in fslint (findup). I'm wondering though with MD5 + SHA1 at <64 + <80 bits of collision (<144 bits), then SHA-2 384 (at 192 bits) must be better even though it's only one hash right?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to hash each object and store the hashes in some sort of table? To test for duplicates, you just do a quick lookup in the table.

[Mystery data structure???](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

As for a "famous algorithm" to accomplish this task, take a look at [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).